# Programmatically create Gatsby slug from Excel data. Want to change getNode(node.parent) line, but this does not work

Tags: reactjs, excel, graphql, gatsby, slug

I use Excel data as a data source. I want to create slug dynamically and use Gatsby docs as an example. https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-seven/
But this does not work, because I don't use Markdown files. I changed 'MarkdownRemark' to 'ExcelData'.

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode }) => {
  if (node.internal.type === `ExcelData`) {
    const fileNode = getNode(node.parent)
    console.log(`\n`, fileNode.relativePath)
  }
}
```

When You look at Gatsby docs,  code print to the terminal two markdown files relative paths:

- pages/sweet-pandas-eating-sweets.md
- pages/pandas-and-bananas.md.

Mine code prints out same path multiple time, because there is only one Excel file.

I try to change the code and use data that is in an Excel file.

```
const fileNode = getNode(_9)
```

But this does not work and I get an errors like:

"gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the onCreateNode lifecycle:
_9 is not defined

```
const fileNode = getNode(node._9)
```

Cannot read property 'relativePath' of undefined

Is it possible to change (node.parent) or not?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-excel/ already?

Gatsby has a new filesystem routing API that means creating routes like this is much easier called the [File System Routing API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/creating-routes/#collection-routing) — this links to the section on Collection Routes which automatically creates pages from every node in a collection without needing to create slugs manually in `gatsby-node.js`.

E.g. your type is `ExcelData` so you'd just need to create a collection route component at `src/pages/{ExcelData.title}.js` (assuming your spreadsheet has a field named `title`) to create pages for all your spreadsheet rows.

This works with any type and any field.